# Android work manager factory returning only one type worker

Tags: android, kotlin, factory-pattern, android-workmanager

I had 2 workManager workers in my app. I added a new worker for DB operation DatabaseSyncWorker. The Database sync worker needed an extra parameter as part of DI. So I created a workerFactory class to inject the extra parameter. But now every time I invoke any other worker, I get only the DatabaseSyncWorker instance. How to get an instance of other workers? I invoke them at diff points of time. They are independent of each other

```
My Factory
class DBSyncWorkerFactory @Inject constructor(private val dao: Dao): WorkerFactory() {
    override fun createWorker(
        appContext: Context,
        workerClassName: String,
        workerParameters: WorkerParameters
    ): ListenableWorker = PolicyWorker(dao, appContext, workerParameters)

}
```

My init of workmanager for DB worker

```
WorkManager.getInstance(App.context).enqueueUniqueWork(
                tag,
                ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
                OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<DBSyncWorker>().build
            )
```

My init of workmanager for networkSyncWorker

```
WorkManager.getInstance(App.context).enqueueUniqueWork(
                tag,
                ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
                OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<NetworkSyncWorker>().build
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. Had to use the `workerClassName` to differentiate between the class name. Solution is below

```
class DBSyncWorkerFactory @Inject constructor(private val dao: Dao): WorkerFactory() {
    override fun createWorker(
        appContext: Context,
        workerClassName: String,
        workerParameters: WorkerParameters
    ): ListenableWorker? {
        return when(workerClassName){
                DBSyncWorker::class.java.name -> DBSyncWorker(dao, appContext, workerParameters)
                NetworkSyncWorker::class.java.name -> NetworkSyncWorker(appContext,workerParameters)
                else ->
                // fall back to the default
                    null
            }
    }
```